# Polyglossia breaks when changing default language from English

Tags: polyglossia, icelandic

I am trying to rework my CV a little and decided I'd just use a plain old `article` format. When I made the CV itself with `lualatex`, `fontspec`, and `polyglossia` it worked fine with `\setdefaultlanguage{icelandic}`. However wen I tried to create a cover letter with the exact same stuff in the preamble (except the  `\let\ps@plain\ps@empty` bit, but I tried taking it out and it made no difference) it didn't work:

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{icelandic}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

% section
\titleformat{\section}
{\itshape\LARGE}
{\scshape \oldstylenums{\thesection}}
{1ex minus .1ex}
{\itshape\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{30pt}{16pt}

\makeatletter
  \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother

\author{\textbf{Þórhalla Guðmundsdóttir Beck} \\ \textit{málvísindamaður -- orðakuklari}}
\title{}
\date{Reykjavík, \today}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\maketitle
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

With an empty file except the `\maketitle` in a `tcolorbox` (I also tried taking them out but it made no difference either), I get the error:

```
! Package polyglossia Error: language english is not loaded. Please load it before using it..
See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
```

If I use `\setmainlanguage{icelandic}` alone (or with `\setdefaultlanguage{english}`) it compiles. If I try putting the language call after all other packages, as suggested in the documentation, it still doesn't compile. And apart from this I couldn't find anything to help me in the documentation. I am starting to think that it's some blindingly obvious misprint or mistake I have made somewhere but I'm not seeing it.

For comparison, here is the preamble from the CV with the same header. It compiles perfectly.

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{icelandic}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

% section
\titleformat{\section}
{\itshape\LARGE}
{\scshape \oldstylenums{\thesection}}
{1ex minus .1ex}
{\itshape\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{30pt}{16pt}

\author{\textbf{Þórhalla Guðmundsdóttir Beck} \\ \textit{málvísindamaður -- orðakuklari}}
\title{Ferilskrá}
\date{Reykjavík, \today}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\maketitle
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

I do realise that I can make it work by using `\setmainlanguage{icelandic}` instead of `\setdefaultlanguage{icelandic}` but I need to know why this isn't working. The `polyglossia` documentation says that you can set the default language with `\setdefaultlanguage` "or, equivalently, \setmainlanguage"! Which begs the question, what is the difference, if any? (and maybe is one preferred over the other?).

Comment: I get no error from your first code. Moreover `\setmainlanguage` and `\setdefaultlanguage` have the same first level expansion, so they're perfectly equivalent.

Comment: that can happen when you switch languages, simply hit enter or s to continue the next compilation should be fine. Or delete the aux-file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is raised when you change the default/main language.

If you have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

text

\end{document}
```

and run it, you'll get no error. But if you change the language line into

```
\setmainlanguage{icelandic}
```

and *don't* remove the `.aux` file, rerunning XeLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX) on the file will produce

```
! Package polyglossia Error: language english is not loaded. Please load it 
before using it..
```

and several other errors *at the first run*. The next run will end without problems.

So it's not a question of `\setmainlanguage` or `\setdefaultlanguage`, but of main language change. Actually, the two commands are defined in exactly the same way, so this *cannot* be the issue.

I agree that `polyglossia` might be more friendly when the main language is changed and not produce scores of error messages, but that's a different problem.

Comment: I removed the .aux files and reran it and it compiled fine. Thanks. I've had problems before where doing that fixed it. Should have thought of that. But at least I was right in that it was something completely obvious that I was missing. #headdesk